# TFS State Changed Date not Working

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, scrum

We're using the Scrum 1.0 template for TFS. We're trying to do a work item query and I've noticed the `State Changed Date` for all of our items is empty. If I do a search for `Changed Date`, that works fine, but doesn't produce the desired results...

Why would this be the case?

Comment: It's unclear what results you are looking for then.

Comment: I'm looking for the last date the state was changed....one would think this should be stored in the state changed date field........

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Export the WIT (Task, Bug or Impediment) using the [Process Editor](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/site/search?query=Team%20Foundation%20Server%20Power%20Tools&f%5B2%5D.Value=Team%20Foundation%20Server%20Power%20Tools&f%5B2%5D.Type=SearchText&f%5B0%5D.Value=tools&f%5B0%5D.Type=RootCategory&f%5B1%5D.Value=power%20tool&f%5B1%5D.Type=Tag&ac=4) or [witadmin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd236914.aspx) to a file.
2. Add the following block within the  element:

   ```
   <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StateChangeDate" name="State Change Date" type="DateTime">
      <WHENCHANGED field="System.State">
        <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
      </WHENCHANGED>
      <WHENNOTCHANGED field="System.State">
       <READONLY />
      </WHENNOTCHANGED>
    <HELPTEXT>Date and time that the value of the State field changed. </HELPTEXT>
   </FIELD>
   ```
3. Save the file, and import it back to TFS using the Process Editor or witadmin..
4. Click the Refresh button on Team Explorer.
5. From this point forward changing the state of a work item will be queryable.

   [image: Adding "State Change Date" to Visual Studio Scrum Process Template]

Comment: An answer with just a link isn't a good idea. Leads to link rot. Can you please restate/summarize the solution in your answer?